# How to format a view to show content but without a teaser?

Tags: views, 10

I want to format a View to show content but without a teaser.

I can choose `fields` instead `content` but then I don't get all the CSS sytling I get with `content`.

I can hide the teaser in the View page with CSS as follows but I don't think that's good SEOwise.

```css
.node--view-mode-teaser .node__content {
    display: none;
}
```

How to format a view to show content but without a teaser?

### Update after Patrick's comment

[image]

Comment: Is your question: How do I show the full text of the node body instead of the summary?

Comment: @PatrickKenny no, I don't want to show the full text. I do wish to show the "content" yes, but just without the teaser or summary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "content".  If you are using Fields, you should be able to delete the body field and then no teaser or summary will be displayed.

Comment: @PatrickKenny I believe that the screenshot I've attached would clarify my intent.

Answer (score 3):

I advise you to use `content` rather than `fields`.

In view `content`, you can choose a `view mode`. Choose the view mode that suits you (full, teaser) or you can create one for your needs. In this example, the view mode is called "accroche" :

[image]

Go to to your content type / manage display. In this view mode you put the fields that you want to display in your view :

[image]

This way, you keep your css and it’s easier to manage if you modify your templates.